# Overleaf: is it possible to select, delete, or move multiple files at the same time?

Tags: latex, tex

I haven't found a way to select multiple files at the same time on overleaf, which makes deleting or moving many files very time consuming.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You'd have to contact their support team: support@overleaf.com

Answer (score 13):

The only way I have discovered to delete multiple files uploaded in an overleaf project is to select them one by one while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> should be hold down when you select a new file by the left mouse button), and then pressing the standard 'Delete' option (in the file-tree panel), which will then apply to all the files selected. So, its quite an 'intuitive' approach.

Still, another 'intuitive' way of selecting multiple objects with <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is not working in Overleaf. Hope someone knows how to implement such method, which will not require a one-by-one selection prior to deleting.

Comment: Would be nice to see `Shift` working. Is there a way to submit such bug /feature requests to Overleaf?

Answer (score 1):

For now (20220411), there is still no good way to delete multiple files at the same time. The best way now, is holding Ctrl button and click files one by one. Then you select many files, you can choose to left-click the trash button or right-click and then click delete. There will be a pop-up window for you to confirm.

Unlike Windows or any other selecting files logic, you cannot use Shift to click the first and the last figures in order to select them all.

Also, the deleting process has a relatively slow animation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you may push 'ctrl' and select multiple files to delete.

It seems like the following figure:

[image]